# Jquery Mobile - Update List Row containing images, text !

Tags: javascript, jquery, android

I am new to Jquery!

I am trying to load a list dynamically, without the page being refreshed. I will be getting data(parsed) from an array which i have to load in the list dynamically.

Its basically a contact list with Chat icon, Username, Presence or status, and Custom message which are part of the list.

Kindly share any code snippet or example which would help me in accomplishing this task quickly

Tx !

Comment: what have you tried so far? we will not do your work for you (at least not for free)

Comment: I gave it a try w.r.t to Presence icon where the options would be Green, Orange, Red and Grey. I have four icons in my local folder using which i update the page using on button click. But i want someone to help me as to how should i read an array consisting the details and update the contact list accordingly, an example would help

Answer (score 0):

Well, make the ajax call, update the html, then call refresh() on the list per the docs.  That would be the first thing I would try.

> Updating lists
>
> If you add items to a listview, you'll
>   need to call the refresh() method on
>   it to update the styles and create any
>   nested lists that are added. For
>   example, $('ul').listview('refresh');
>
> We're currently working on a few
>   improvements to the refresh method, so
>   keep your eye on Github for updates.
>   
> http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/lists/docs-lists.html